# Prove that if |, then |, for any , , ,  ∈ ℕ

Tags: proof-writing

Prove that if |, then |, for any , , ,  ∈ ℕ

So I have, if abc|cd, then abc(k) = cd. I'm very confused on how to continue

Comment: Try to manipulate the equation so it is in the form $ab (m) = bcd$.

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Never introduce division in an elementary number theory question about divisibility.  Factoring is fine.  Dividing is not.  This is generally taught *before* division is formally introduced.

Comment: @JMoravitz Got it, thx

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**

Since $abc\mid cd$ we know that there is some integer $k$ such that $abck = cd$

If we were to multiply both sides by $b$...

> Then $ab(bck)=bcd$ and noting that $bck$ is an integer...